# issue in while using `WorkContinuation.combine()` when WorkManger is initialized using dagger2

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-architecture-components, android-workmanager

I've been using workManager and it works fine with dagger2 but when i used  `WorkContinuation.combine()` for chaining there was an issue in WorkerFactory
My workers didn't initialze

crash report is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown worker class name: androidx.work.impl.workers.CombineContinuationsWorker
        at incubasys.aydo.repositories.worker.WorkerFactory.createWorker(WorkerFactory.kt:22)
        at androidx.work.WorkerFactory.createWorkerWithDefaultFallback(WorkerFactory.java:81)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker(WorkerWrapper.java:228)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run(WorkerWrapper.java:127)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

WorkerFactory where the crash happens

```
class DaggerWorkerFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val workerFactories: Map<Class<out ListenableWorker>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ChildWorkerFactory>>
) : WorkerFactory() {
    override fun createWorker(
        appContext: Context,
        workerClassName: String,
        workerParameters: WorkerParameters
    ): ListenableWorker? {
        val foundEntry =
            workerFactories.entries.find { Class.forName(workerClassName).isAssignableFrom(it.key) }
//crashes here
        val factoryProvider = foundEntry?.value
            ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown worker class name: $workerClassName")
        return factoryProvider.get().create(appContext, workerParameters)
    }
}
```

it only crashes when i use `WorkContinuation.combine()`.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to call `WorkContinuation.combine()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WorkContinuation.combine()` adds an instance of the `CombineContinuationsWorker` class to your continuation.
This means that your WorkerFactory needs to handle this class names when creating the actual worker class.

You have two options:

1. You handle `CombineContinuationsWorker` to your workerFactory
2. You use a [`delegatingWorkerFactory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/DelegatingWorkerFactory) and add your factory to it so that it returns `null` when it does not find the correct class name. 
   The `delegatingWorkerFactory` will then use the default workerFactory to instantiate the right class.

Personally I prefer the second option as it handles whatever will change in WorkManager and you can potentially add more/different Worker Factories that handle different pieces/module of your application.

Comment: thanks.. I realized that after some research
and i removed `throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown worker class name: $workerClassName")` this line of code from the factory since the `createWorker` method retruns `nullable` `ListenableWorker` so the Instance of `CombineContinuationsWorker `  is not handled by my factory anymore.. and it works..

Answer (score 0):

You should return `null` from your `WorkerFactory` to delegate to the default `WorkerFactory`.

You *don't* need a `DelegatingWorkerFactory`.